# Counterpoint generation software?

Tags: music

[Foox](https://github.com/ntoll/foox) "Creates species counterpoint using genetic algorithms (in Python)."

Are there any other open-source counterpoint generation software?

Comment: Hi Geremia - this sort of question doesn't really fit here. I'll migrate to Software Recommendations in the hope someone will have an answer.